# training loss goes down, but validation loss fluctuates wildly, when same dataset is passed as training and validation dataset in keras

Tags: validation, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

[image: training and validation losses]

(1) I am using the same preprocessing steps for the training and validation set.
(2) Passing the same dataset as the training and validation set.
(3) Having the same number of steps per epochs (steps per epoch = dataset len/batch len) for training and validation loss.

The training loss goes down as expected, but the validation loss (on the same dataset used for training) is fluctuating wildly.

My intent is to use a held-out dataset for validation, but I saw similar behavior on a held-out validation dataset. So, I thought I'll pass the training dataset as validation (for testing purposes) - still see the same behavior.

What can be going on?

Comment: train loss is not calculated as validation loss by keras: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10426#issuecomment-397485072

Comment: So does this mean the training loss is computed on just one batch, while the validation loss is the average over all batches? Even then, how is the training loss falling over subsequent epochs. I have set the shuffle parameter to False - so, the batches are sequentially selected.

Comment: train is the average of all batches, validation is computed one-shot on all... the training loss is falling, what's the problem. take care of overfitting

Comment: Do you use an architecture with batch normalization? This is just a guess (given the lack of details), but make sure that if you use batch normalization, you account for training/evaluation mode (i.e., set the model to eval model for validation). This might explain different behavior on the same set (as you evaluate on the training set):

Comment: Since the validation loss is fluctuating, it will be better you save the best only weights monitoring the validation loss using ModelCheckpoint callback and evaluate on a test set.